# Функция указывающая на определенный символ для задания критерия условию в VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Здраствуйте, у меня возник вопрос, при доработке скрипта по форматированию телефонных номеров я столкнулся с проблемой, что не понимаю\ не могу найти функцию как можно в VBA при составлении условия для форматирования, задать как параметр первый символ номера, тобешь что-бы в конце(место с 3мя звездочками) скрипт форматировал номера которые начинались с 8 (поскольку проблема заключается в том, что если номер начинается с +7 и где то в номере есть еще 8 то на выходе получается номер с 2мя +7 по типу такого +7 954 954 +74 34 когда действительный номер должен выглядеть так +7 954 954 84 34), есть мысль что это надо добавлять переменную, выносить первую цифру в другую ячейку и сравнивать эту ячейку с переменной и если все верно то переделывать номер, но это по-моему слишком громоздкое\нерациональное решение, поэтому я хотел спросить есть ли варианты это сделать проще, или где можно почитать на эту тему. Благодарю за уделенное время.

```
Public Function PrepareNumbers(InputString As String)
   Dim i As Long, newString As String
   For i = 1 To Len(InputString)
       If IsNumeric(Mid(InputString, i, 1)) Or (i = 1 And Mid(InputString, i, 1) = "+") Then
           newString = newString & Mid(InputString, i, 1)
       End If
   Next i
   If Len(newString) = 11 And InStr(newString, 7) = 1 Then
       newString = "+" & newString
   End If
       PrepareNumbers = Replace(newString, "+7", "8", 1, 1)
       If Len(InputString) = 11 and ***Mid(InputString,,)*** Then
            PrepareNumbers = Replace(newString, "8", "+7", 1, 1)
   End If
```

Comment: Можно вставить проверку на вхождение символа "+" в строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Public Function PrepareNumbers(InputString As String)
    Dim i As Long, newString As String
    For i = 1 To Len(InputString)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(InputString, i, 1)) Or (i = 1 And Mid(InputString, i, 1) = "+") Then
            newString = newString & Mid(InputString, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(newString) = 11 Then
        If InStr(newString, "7") = 1 Then
            newString = "+" & newString
        Elseif InStr(newString, "8") = 1 Then
            newString = "+7" & Right(newString, Len(newString)-1)
        Else
            newString = "!!! " & newString
        End if
    Else
        newString = "!!! " & newString
    End If
    PrepareNumbers = newString
End Function`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @01e9, `+71234567890` - выдаст ошибку, хотя номер записан корректно 
`+81234567890` - такую запись не преобразует в`+71234567890`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function PrepareNumbers2(InputString As String) As String
    Dim sStr As String ', j As Long '
    
    sStr = Replace(InputString, "+", "")
    
'    For j = 1 To Len(InputString) '
'        If IsNumeric(Mid$(InputString, j, 1)) Then sStr = sStr & Mid$(InputString, j, 1) '
'    Next j '
    
    If Len(sStr) = 11 Then
        Select Case Left$(sStr, 1)
        Case "7": sStr = "+" & sStr
        Case "8": sStr = "+7" & Mid$(sStr, 2)
        Case Else: sStr = "Err"
        End Select
    Else
        sStr = "Err"
    End If
    
    PrepareNumbers2 = sStr
End Function
```

B таком варианте в фунцию передается номер, состоящий только из цифр и знака "+". Если нужно чистить от мусора - раскомментировать переменную и цикл, закомментировать или удалить строку

```
    sStr = Replace(InputString, "+", "")
```

Для варианта, когда количество символов *<>11*, вместо `sStr = "Err"` можно организовать дополнительные проверки для корректировки номера. Как пример:

```
If Len(sStr) = 10 And Left$(sStr, 1) <> "7" And Left$(sStr, 1) <> "8" Then
    sStr = "+7" & sStr
Else
    sStr = "Err"
End If
```